# How to check if a user is logged in. Angular 12.1.2

Tags: angular

My backend sets a JWT after successful register/login, however what will be the most efficient way to check if a user is logged in? Check if the user has the signed cookie?

Comment: If the cookie is HttpOnly, you won't be able to even check for the presence of the cookie via JavaScript. You will need a value that's accessible via local, session or cookie storage to check for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a logic not tied to Angular. You can store your JWT token in local storage and create a GET request that requires the same token to be passed to return the user profile for example. Throw an error if the service receives no/invalid token. You can call this service at the component CanActivate level.

As a security recommendation, make sure to pass the token in a custom header to protect your app from CSRF attacks.